# How to add TestCase to Defect in Rally?

Tags: rally, testcase, defects

I have a list of TestCases.
After few iteration we have some test cases that fails. We have defect for them but some defects cause fail of few TC.

So here is my question how we can connect TestCase with defect not by creating defect from TestCase?
I want to do that from Web.